# email share button not adding body text in email using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, email

I have a simple app where I would like the user to share youtube video to email on click here is I have tried so far

```
import React from 'react'

function kiki() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
            <a className="video-email_button button-hover" href={`mailto:?subject=I wanted you to see this site&amp;body=Check out this video https://youtu.be/yul2-4mc6mg`} title="Share viaEmail">
                <span className="video-email_button-icon">
                    <ReactSVG src={shareEnvelopeSVG} />
                    </span>
                <span className="video-email_button-text">Email</span>
            </a>

            </div>
                
        </div>
    )
}

export default kiki
```

Here is live demo : [LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m5hzl6)

Unfortunately, the only subject title is added to the email, as below image shows
[image]

Why body text is not added to the email ???

Comment: Could you try by replacing `&amp;` by `&` ?

Comment: @Scalpweb the same  :(

Comment: Works absolutely fine for me, with the link in your stackblitz demo. You should apply proper URL-encoding to the parameter values though, to increase compatibility. But in the end, you will have to accept that this still depends on the used mail client, whether all those parameters will actually do anything.

Comment: @CBroe can you share the screen if it adds body text on email ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be working. Replaced the `&amp` with `&body`

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       <div className="container">
            <a className="video-email_button button-hover" href={`mailto:?subject=I wanted you to see this site&body=Check out this video https://youtu.be/yul2-4mc6mg`} title="Share viaEmail">
                <span className="video-email_button-text">Email</span>
            </a>

            </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```